# Restoring WAS7.0 CAR file to WAS 8.5

Tags: ibm-was, server-migration

My current application setup is running with **WAS 7.0** and we are planning to migrate with **WAS 8.5**. 
Since my application is having lot of complex console setup like Queues , Activation Spec, multiple data sources , security configs, work manager etc... 
So, I thought of using a **WAS 7.0** CAR file in **WAS 8.5** to restore the profile configuration.

Is it possible to do that or do we have to configure manually in **WAS 8.5**?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I've never tried that, but you have some other supported migration paths:

- Use migration wizard/migration tools - see [Migrating product configurations](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/tmig_admin.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-4-0-2&lang=en) for details - this will scan your v7.0 profile configuration and create v 8.5.5 profile. Probably the easiest, if you have lots of customized changes and dont have any scripts relating to them.
- Use [WebSphere Configuration Migration Tool](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Configuration_Migration_Tool) - this tool is installed as plugin to Eclipse. Reads exported configuration and creates jython script. Tool migrates most common resources (like JDBC), but not all. See above page for limitations.
- Use AdminTask which exports configuration as property file, change it according to your needs and update on target environment.

  ```
  wsadmin(.sh/.bat) –lang jython –c “AdminTask.extractConfigProperties(['-propertiesFileName my.props'])”
  ```

  See [Managing environment configurations with properties files using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_7modenvconfig.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. Let me try exploring these options. :-)